# How do I create a web page to show dynamic data?

Tags: html, dynamic

I have a microcontroller that monitors 4 different sensor variables (temperature, pressure, weight, speed) with each variable being read at a different rate. The microcontroller also runs a lightweight webserver.  I want to create a simple webpage such that when a client connection is  made to the webserver, it will display the values of the 4 variables.  While I am somewhat familiar with HTML I can’t figure out how to populate a webpage with the data.
Am looking for some pointers on how to do this.

Secondly, I know the page that is displayed is static.  How can it be made dynamic in that when a new value is read, the page is updated with that value.

I am sure there are ‘standard’ ways to do this but I have no clue what the mechanisms are called or how they work.
Any guidance is really appreciated. – Thanks!
J

Comment: This isn't a very good question for Stackoverflow because it doesn't deal with a specific problem is and is asking for general advice. Lots of different people have different solutions for getting started, but I think that learning PHP is probably the easiest place to start. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OK_JCtrrv-c

Comment: Actually, I am interested in pointers to the architectural approaches and their names. (IDK what they are called)   A language is used to implement the architectural approach but without a description, learning the language is dubious.  Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

1. Perhaps **SSI** (**S**erver **S**ide **I**ncludes) is what you need to show dynamic data inside HTML page.  Usually lightweight webserver for micro-controller would had this feature implemented already.
2. You need to implement Web 2.0 feature by yourself to extend your lightweight webserver. For client side you can use the js library from [Socket.IO](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-api/)

Alternatively you can have a socket.io server (by python) play for this web 2.0 feature, and your micro-control just update its data to the web server by JSON API. Then socket.io server update the received data to the clients. This is what I've done on my previous MCU project.